# Are there examples for using the ERRest framework?

Tags: webobjects

I am trying to create a REST API using Project Wonder's [ERRest.framework](http://wiki.wocommunity.org/display/documentation/ERRest+Framework) for WebObjects. Can anybody show me a REST API example using the ERRest framework?

thanks

Raghu

Answer (score 0):

There's a [tutorial introduction](https://wiki.wocommunity.org/display/WEB/Your+First+Rest+Project) over at the [Project Wonder](http://wiki.wocommunity.org/display/documentation/Home) wiki.